# I said to Allah that I won't play Chess again. But now I get tempted to play it

Tags: sin, oaths, game

A month earlier, Allah blessed me and now I pray 5 times a day (Alhumdulillah). I used to play Chess, and I also said to Allah that I won't play Chess from now on because it was taking a lot of my time. I haven't played Chess for more than a month now but I get really tempted to play it.

Is Chess now haram on me? Or do I need to give a kaffara? Can I even play it again in life?

Please help me so the Satanic waswasas go away. Remember that I did not take an oath or swear in front of Allah. I just said "No Chess from now on".

May Allah forgive my sins.

Comment: If you pray on time. Why should chess be haram on you when it clearly helps to make plans and learn to think strategically?

Comment: I am asking once I said to Allah that I won't play Chess again, can I pay penance for it and play it or not? Thanks

Comment: Did you say it or made an oath there's a huge difference. If you made an oath the ruling is rather clear.